# Prevent lesson videos from being accessed directly | e-learning

Tags: php, .htaccess, video

e-learning platform: The instructor of a course will be uploading videos while creating lessons for the course.

Diagram

```
             create            has            consists of
instructor ---------> course ------> lesson --------------> video
```

When GET request is made for the lesson **l1** of the course **c1** by the students, the server will respond back the following JSON response (if student is logged in and signed up for the course)

```
{
    "success" : [
        {
            "courseid" : "c1",
            "lessonid" : "l1",
            "title" : "Sample lesson #1",
            "video" : "http://www.example.com/lesson/l1/video.mp4",
            "videothumbnail" : "http://www.example.com/lesson/l1/videothumbnail.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Requirement**

Make lesson video accessible only from
**http://www.example.com/course?courseid=c1&lessonid=l1**
page when student is logged in and signed up for the course.

**What I have done**

I have prevented the direct access of the lesson video by writing the following line in **.htaccess** file which I have placed inside the **lesson** folder.

```
#prevent direct access to the lesson folder and its contents
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Where, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the IP address of the server.

I even tried the following:

```
#prevent direct access to the lesson folder and its contents
deny from all
```

Now if the video link is copy-pasted in a browser the following error message is shown.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /lesson/l1/video.mp4 on this server.
```

So, it is successfully preventing direct access of the video when I copy paste the video link in the browser http://www.example.com/lesson/l1/video.mp4

**Issue**

But when I try to access the video from the course page http://www.example.com/course?courseid=c1&lessonid=l1 I get the following error message in the browser console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Kindly suggest a way to make the lesson video only accessible from the course page.

Backend

- API in php
- MySQL db
- Redis for caching

Comment: When a client opens your page his PC IP will not be same as the server IP so definitely he will not be able to see that.

Comment: @AmitRay i even tried deny from all and removed the server IP part, still not works

Comment: Please look at the answer by Nikhil Pradeep. it may help you. Also please note that it is very difficult to stop downloads of video if a person is allowed to view it.

Comment: @AmitRay working on it

Answer (score 1):

You can just move the includes folder out of the web-root. If you want to block direct access to the whole includes folder then you can put a .htaccess file in that folder that contains just:

```
deny from all
```

Like this you cannot open any file from that folder and you can include them in php without any problems.